# How to generate .so file with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a native library with source code (in CPP) which is configured to be built in AOSP environment. So, if I directly call NDK-build with its Android.mk, there are lots of missing dependencies.

Is it possible to import this Android.mk into Android Studio and generate .so file from Android Studio?

I searched online and found that if I have a Java Android project and would like to use this library in it, I can add native support to it. When I build the Java project, Android Studio will generate the so file first.

However, what I need is just the so file. I do not want to create a Java Android project and write corresponding JNI calls for that. Is there an easier way to just compile these native sources into so file with Android Studio?

Comment: I don't know. I just build the apk, open apk file as zip archive and copy .so files from libs folder :D

Comment: Not necessarily. Some AOSP native libraries can be compiled with NDK, others have non-public AOSP dependencies, and cannot be built standalone.